# want to use getRow inside allRowsValid for sudoku solver how can i solve it?

Tags: javascript, solver, sudoku

So i have been trying to write a sudoku solver and i had to complet methods inside an extend class here's the head of the code:

```
class Board extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(board) {
    super();

    this.board = board || [
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ];
  }

  getRow(index) {
    return this.board[index];
  }
```

here i have to check if all the rows inside that board are valid (from 1 to 9 no repet):

```
allrowsValid() {
  for (let c = 0; c < 9; ++c) {
    **var row = this.getRow(c)** ***//what i need to fix***

      for ( let num = 1; num <= 9; ++num){
        if (this.board[row][c] === num) {
          return false;
      }
      }
    }
    return true;
    }
```

How can i solve it ?
thanks !

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether "valid" means "full house" (all numbers in range [1-9]), or not invalid (some numbers in range [1-9] without repetition). I've used bit arithmetic to specifically address this in Sudoku in the past:

```
// class methods...

validHouse( array) {
    // no non zero repetitions
    let allowed = 0b1111111110;
    for( let index = 9; index--;) {
        if( array[index]) {
            let position  = 1 << array[index];
            if( !(allowed & position)) {
                 return false; // repetition
            }
            allowed &= ~position;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

fullHouse(array) {
    // all house numbers completed
    let required = 0b1111111110;
    for( let index = 9; index--;) {
        if( array[index]) {
            let position  = 1 << array[index];
            required &= ~position;
        }
    }
    return required == 0;
}
```

So if you wanted to know if all rows were complete or valid you could use

```
allRowsFull() {
    return this.board.every(row => this.fullHouse(row));
}

allRowsValid() {
   return this.board.every(row => this.validHouse(row));
}
```

The point here is not to push you into using binary arithmetic (it's an acquired taste<sup>1</sup>) but to point out that a row is only one of the three types of Sudoku houses (row, column and box) that need to be considered.

---

<sup>1</sup> Answer updated to use the bit-wise complement operator (`~`) instead of the logical not operator (`!`) in bit clearing operations. They are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (this.board[row][c] === num)
```

The problem is at this line, you are trying to get the row by using the row. The `row` variable is already referencing the row.

So the solution is to replace `this.board[row][c]` with `row[c]`

```js
for ( let num = 1; num <= 9; ++num){
    if (row[c] === num) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks that helped me to return true if all rows are valid but it should return false if at least one row has a conflict, can you help me please

Comment: allrowsValid() {
    for (var c = 0; c <= 9; ++c) {
      var row = this.getRow(c)
      for ( var num = 1; num <= 9; ++num){
        for (row = 0; row - 1; ++row){ // i added this line to make it return true if all rows are valid.
        if (row[c] === num) {
          return false;
      }
    }
      }
    }
    return true;
}